# ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex allow release twice?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-leaks, release, addressbook

```
ABMultiValueRef phones = ABRecordCopyValue(ref, kABPersonPhoneProperty);
if ( phones ) {
    for(int i=0;i<ABMultiValueGetCount(phones);i++) {
        NSString* label=(NSString*)ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(phones, i);
        CFRelease ((CFTypeRef)label);
        CFRelease ((CFTypeRef)label);
    }
}
CFRelease(phones);
```

Why **label** can be released twice without any error? but **phones** cannot.
Any memory leak if not release **label** for twice?

I had run above code successfully in xcode4 simulator 4.3

Comment: try doing this NSLog ([NSString stringWithFormat:@"Label retainCount : %d", [label retainCount]]); after you do CFRelease and see what shows up in your debugger

Comment: The label retainCount is: 2 => 1 => 1
The phones retainCount is: 2 => 1

Comment: ABAddressBookRef from ABAddressBookCreate() return retainCount is: 1. 
CFArrayRef from ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople() return retainCount is: 1.
ABRecordRef from CFArrayGetValueAtIndex() return retainCount is: 2.
Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter why this doesn't crash. You absolutely shouldn't be doing it. The contract this function has with you is it returns a value which you **must release exactly once**. Whatever else it does with this value internally (e.g. caching) that may cause this to not crash is irrelevant.